# An outer measure defined on $\mathbb {R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $s, \delta \in (0,1)$. Consider the outer measure on $\mathbb{R}$, $\mu^s_{\delta}$, defined by
\begin{align*}
    \mu^s_{\delta}(E):=\inf \left\{\sum_{j}\lvert I_{j}\rvert^s: E \subset \bigcup_{j} I_{j}: I_{j} \text { closed intervals, } \lvert I_j\rvert\leq\delta\right\}.
\end{align*}
For an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\lvert I\rvert$ denotes the length of $I$. I want to prove that if $E$ is an interval and $\delta< \lvert E\rvert$, then
\begin{align*}
    \mu^s_{\delta}(E) \geq  \delta^{s-1}\left|E\right|-\delta^s.
\end{align*}
I think that by definition, $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $\mu^s_{\delta}(E)+\epsilon\geq \sum_{j}\left|I_{j}\right|^s\geq \left(\sum_{j}\left|I_{j}\right|\right)^s\geq \left|E\right|^s>\delta^s.$ I wonder how to get $\delta^{s-1}$. I feel like I need to show that the delta cover is the smallest one among all the best covers, thankswhich is achieved through infimum. Such a delta cover is a little bit larger than $\delta^{s-1}\left|E\right|-\delta^{s}$.

Comment: What does "make $\delta$ as many as possible" mean?

Comment: @LSpice Sorry, it should be as few as possible since I don't want too many summands, just the right amount to cover $E$.

Comment: But what does it mean to make $\delta$ as many, *or* as few, as possible?  Isn't $\delta$ fixed?  Do you mean as few *intervals* of length $\delta$ as possible?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, that's what I mean, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta\newcommand\ol\overline$Your goal cannot be attained in general. Indeed, suppose that $\de\in(0,1/2)$. Take any interval $E$ of length $\de_1:=|E|\in(\de,2\de)$. Then for the closure $\ol E$ of $E$ and some closed intervals $I_1$ and $I_2$ of lengths $|I_1|=\de$ and $|I_2|=\de_1-\de\le\de$ we have $E=I_1\cup I_2$, so that
$$\mu_\de^s(E)\le|I_1|^s+|I_2|^s
=\de^s+(\de_1-\de)^s\underset{\de_1\downarrow\de}\longrightarrow
\de^s<\de^{s-1}-\de^s,$$
so that for some interval $E$ with $\de<|E|$ we have
$$\mu_\de^s(E)\not\ge\de^{s-1}-\de^s.$$

(It is actually easy to see that for any interval $E$ of length $t$ we have $\mu_\de^s(E)=k\de^s+(t-k\de)^s$, where $k:=\lfloor t/\de\rfloor$.)

Comment: Do ypu mean $(k\delta)^s$ in the last equality?

Comment: Is there any way to show this is the infimum?

Comment: @Analyst_311419 : The term is $k\delta^s$, as written, not $(k\delta)^s$. Since your posted question has been fully answered, please mark it accordingly, to keep things in good order. If you have further questions on the additional statement in the parentheses, you can post them separately, and then I will answer them.